# ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions - rails upgrade 2.3.x to 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

In my **rails2.3.11** `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` I have this

```
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions::rescue_responses["ActionController::RoutingError"] = :not_found
```

now this feature is deprecated in **rails-3.2.11**, I am getting this server log

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions.rescue_responses is deprecated. Please configure your exceptions using a railtie or in your application config instead. (called from ApplicationController at /home/mbussey/demo/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31)
```

May be my question is duplicated but I need specific help on How to set `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions::rescue_responses` in rails3.2.11, so I can't get deprecated warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following line

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses["ActionController::RoutingError"] = :not_found
```

or you can

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!( 'ActionController::RoutingError' => :not_found)
```

In `config/environments/` env files you should be able to add (production.rb, development.rb or test.rb) or `config/application.rb` for all environments

please let me know if this will work for you